# MySQL error #1064, at delete statement in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure in MySQL using PHP web interface for MySQL:

```
DELIMITER \\
CREATE PROCEDURE Remove_Product (IN id INT)
{
    BEGIN
    DELETE Product WHERE ProductId=id;
    END \\  
}
DELIMITER ;
```

but I am stuck with error #1064:

> Error: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your >MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near WHERE ProductId=id; at line 3.

How can I resolve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. It should be

```
DELETE FROM Product WHERE ProductId=id;
```

The `FROM` is not optional. See [the manual on the `DELETE` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html).

Comment: thank you very much. this worked. i thought "FROM" is necessary when joins are involved